# Should we "flag for editing"?

Tags: discussion, editing

I've noticed a few questions and answers that are high quality and valuable, but appear to have typos or missing words in places. In cases where I understand the meaning, I can simply edit to correct this. However, in many cases I'm out of my depth and simply can't guess what was intended - especially when terms are used that I am unfamiliar with.

It would be nice to be able to flag such posts for someone more knowledgeable to edit, rather than just ignoring them when they are beyond me.

So two questions:

- Would it be useful to draw attention and improve such posts?
- If so, how can we do this?

We obviously don't want to use the existing flag system as that will bring mods, who shouldn't have to do all the editing...  I'm trying to think of a way that doesn't introduce too much extra effort. Maybe someone else can think of something?

Comment: You could add a comment. Im pretty sure im guilty of this. But typing on my mobile is a hastle and it dont have a good spellchecker. Its not like anybody intentionally does this.

Comment: @joojaa exactly - it isn't to make a criticism, just to share the work out. I'd rather people who have good questions and answers get on with posting them rather than worry about typos...

Answer (score 1):

As was already pointed outby @joojaa in the comments - this is a good reason to use comments.

First - it is definitely worth drawing attention to good posts with unclear parts! If it's unclear to you, it may well be unclear to others. So go ahead and ask for clarification!

Second - use comments, not flags. Flags are meant to draw moderator attention to problematic issues - very low quality posts, spam posts, questions that ask for opinions instead of expertise...
But the situation you describe is that the posts are good, just parts of them are unclear. So ask the OP and the community to clarify - comment and  explain what is unclear. An improved post benefits all.

After the clarification is made, and the necessary edits to the post are done (either by the community or the OP) then the comments can be deleted again.

Answer (score 0):

We could make a "basic" editing, asking for better ones in the comment. Unfortunately my english is far from good so i don't know if i could help about this topic.